# Binding a combobox associated with another combobox in aspxgridview

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, devexpress, datagridviewcombobox

I want to bind cities combox associated with countries combobox in devexpress gridview's insert/update mode. My datas in a database so I need db connection. Which way should I try? 
Thanks for your suggestions.

Çağın

Comment: show some code, how are you loading all cities right now? Question like you asked is too broad and vague. Are you having issues in loading data from database or in using the DevExpress controls?

Comment: I use SqlDataSource for binding cities. Selecting cities of selected country is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is cascading combo boxes example in DevExpress demos:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/CascadingComboBoxes.aspx

Demo uses combo box callback. Alternatively you can implement this using ajax calls in combination with combo box client functionality. Link to ASPxClientComboBox documentation:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBoxtopic